# Reading living process memory without interrupting it

Tags: linux, memory

I would like to explore the memory of a living process, and when I do so, the process must not get disturbed - so attaching gdb to the process (which would stop it) is not an option.
Therefore I would like to get this info from /proc/kcore (if you know of another way to do this please let me know).
So I made a little experiment. I created a file called TEST with only "EXTRATESTEXTRA" inside.
Then I opened it with less

```
$ less TEST
```

I got the PID of this process with

```
$ ps aux | grep TEST
user    7785  0.0  0.0  17944   992 pts/8    S+   16:15   0:00 less TEST
user    7798  0.0  0.0  13584   904 pts/9    S+   16:16   0:00 grep TEST
```

And then I used this script to create a dump of all files :

```
#!/bin/bash
grep rw-p /proc/$1/maps | sed -n 's/^\([0-9a-f]*\)-\([0-9a-f]*\) .*$/\1 \2/p' | while read start stop; do gdb --batch --pid $1 -ex "dump memory $1-$start-$stop.dump 0x$start 0x$stop"; done
```

(I found it on this site https://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file)

```
$ sudo ./dump_all_pid_memory.sh 7785
```

After this, I looked for "TRATESTEX" in all dumped files :

```
$ grep -a -o -e '...TRATESTEX...' ./*.dump
./7785-00624000-00628000.dump:HEXTRATESTEXTRA
./7785-00b8f000-00bb0000.dump:EXTRATESTEXTRA
./7785-00b8f000-00bb0000.dump:EXTRATESTEXTRA
```

So I concluded that there must be an occurance of this string somewhere between 0x00624000 and 0x00628000 .
Therefore I converted the offsets into decimal numbers and used dd to get the memory from /proc/kcore :

```
$ sudo dd if="/proc/kcore" of="./y.txt" skip="0" count="1638400" bs=1
```

To my surprise, the file y.txt was full of zeros (I didn't find the string I was looking for in it).

As a bonus surprise, I ran a simmilar test at the same time with a different test file and found that the other test string i was using 
(both processes with less were running at the same time) should be found at the same location (the dumping and greping gave the same offset).
So there must be something I don't understand clearly.

- Isn't the /proc/pid/maps supposed to show the offset of the memory (i.e. : if it would say "XXX" is at offset 0x10, another program could not be using the same offset am I right? - this is the source of my second surprise)
- How can I read /proc/kmap to get the memory that belongs to a process which's pid I know ?

Comment: AFAIK, `/proc/kcore` is the kernels memory space. Perhaps `/proc/<pid>/mem` is more appropriate to what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Why are you asking, and what exactly do you want to achieve??? Did you consider the case when monitoring and monitored processes are on different cores, so run simultaneously (and cbange "randomly" their address space)

Comment: The Python code doesn't run. All I get is an error: `IndentationError: expected an indented block'` in line 5. :(

Comment: @zrajm it should be indented, but even after correct indentation it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Since the 3.2 kernel we have a process_vm_readv system call to read memory directly from another process.

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Comment: When you said "to explore the memory of a living process, and when I do so, the process must not get disturbed" this show you lacking a concept: memory integrity.   Similar to database integrity.   The memory has to be read AS A WHOLE, and all at the same time.   If you read A at time=0, and let process modify memory, and then read B at time=1s, does memory B and memory A has any relationship to each other?   No.  The process may have already wipe out memory A and refresh B, and so your B cannot be correlated with A.

Comment: So to read in chunks, the process must be in STOP mode, via ptrace(STOP) (this is how gdb worked).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For process 1234 you can get its memory map by reading sequentially `/proc/1234/maps` (a textual pseudo-file) and read the virtual memory by e.g. [read(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing or [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html)-ing appropriate segments of the `/proc/1234/mem` sparse pseudo-file.

However, I believe you cannot avoid some kind of synchronization (perhaps with [ptrace(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ptrace.2.html), as `gdb` does), since the process 1234 can (and does) alter its address space at any time (with `mmap` & related syscalls).

The situation is different if the monitored process 1234 is not arbitrary, but if you could improve it to communicate somehow with the monitoring process.

I'm not sure to understand why do you ask this. And `gdb` is able to `watch` some location without stopping the process.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I resolved to monitoring the memory via the /proc/pid/maps and reading the regions specified there from /proc/pid/mem (I edited the question)

Answer (score 42):

If you have root access and are on a linux system, you can use the following linux script (adapted from [Gilles' excellent unix.stackexchange.com answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6302/3986) and the answer originally given in the question above but including SyntaxErrors and not being pythonic):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import sys

def print_memory_of_pid(pid, only_writable=True):
    """ 
    Run as root, take an integer PID and return the contents of memory to STDOUT
    """
    memory_permissions = b'rw' if only_writable else b'r-'
    sys.stderr.write("PID = %d" % pid)
    with open("/proc/%d/maps" % pid, 'rb') as maps_file:
        with open("/proc/%d/mem" % pid, 'rb', 0) as mem_file:
            for line in maps_file.readlines():  # for each mapped region
                m = re.match(rb'([0-9A-Fa-f]+)-([0-9A-Fa-f]+) ([-r][-w])', line)
                if m.group(3) == memory_permissions:
                    sys.stderr.buffer.write(b"\nOK : \n" + line + b"\n")
                    start = int(m.group(1), 16)
                    if start > 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF:
                        continue
                    end = int(m.group(2), 16)
                    sys.stderr.write("start = " + str(start) + "\n")
                    mem_file.seek(start)  # seek to region start
                    chunk = mem_file.read(end - start)  # read region contents
                    sys.stdout.buffer.write(chunk)  # dump contents to standard output
                else:
                    sys.stderr.buffer.write(b"\nPASS : \n" + line + b"\n")

if __name__ == '__main__': # Execute this code when run from the commandline.
    try:
        assert len(sys.argv) == 2, "Provide exactly 1 PID (process ID)"
        pid = int(sys.argv[1])
        print_memory_of_pid(pid)
    except (AssertionError, ValueError) as e:
        print("Please provide 1 PID as a commandline argument.")
        print("You entered: %s" % ' '.join(sys.argv))
        raise e
```

If you save this as write_mem.py, you can run this with python3 (for python2.5–2.7, see the edit history of this answer) as:

```
sudo python3 write_mem.py 1234 > pid1234_memory_dump
```

to dump pid1234 memory to the file pid1234_memory_dump. To suppress the debug messages printed to stderr, `2>/dev/null` can be added.

Comment: The only_writable flag doesn't work, because you're still grabbing both characters in your regex match.

Comment: Please, can somebody edit the script? It has a missing colon at 12 (with open("/proc/%d/maps" % pid, 'r') as maps_file>>(here)<<)

Comment: Script did the trick--I had written quite a bit in a GetSimple blog, not realizing I had been logged out, so when I hit "update" to save my changes, it lost everything. I found it all in the memory dump, though. Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug. It should be `memory_permissions = 'rw' if only_writable else 'r-'`

Comment: The version currently posted/edited works great. I was able to recover critical information that would have otherwise been lost (human error) this way.

Comment: This program has a serious bug: memory integrity. Similar to database integrity. Process memory has to be read AS A WHOLE, and all at the same time.   But real life you are not able to do that.   So we have to read in chunks.   But to read in chunks, the process must be stopped in running mode first, which is achieve via ptrace(STOP).
If you read A at time=0, and the process running may modify memory, and then read B at time=1s. The process may have already wipe out memory A and refresh B, so B cannot be correlated with A at all.

Answer (score 4):

Since the 3.2 version of the kernel. You can use the [process_vm_readv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_readv.2.html) system call to read process memory without interruption.

> ```
> ssize_t process_vm_readv(pid_t pid,
>                                 const struct iovec *local_iov,
>                                 unsigned long liovcnt,
>                                 const struct iovec *remote_iov,
>                                 unsigned long riovcnt,
>                                 unsigned long flags);
> ```
>
> These system calls transfer data between the address space of the
>          calling process ("the local process") and the process identified by
>          pid ("the remote process").  The data moves directly between the
>          address spaces of the two processes, without passing through kernel
>          space.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `/proc/pid/mem` to read process memory. I wouldn't recommend trying to read `/proc/kcore` or any of the kernel memory functions (which is time consuming).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the value of a global variable or a specified address, you can use my tool [gvardump](https://github.com/oufm/gvardump) instead of reading the entire memory.
gvardump will parse the variable address and print its value nicely without causing process interruption.

For example:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/u/trace_test# ./gvardump.py 53670 -a 1 '*g_ss[0].sss[0].ps'
*((g_ss[0]).sss[0]).ps = {
    .a = 6,
    .sss = {
        {
            .bbb = 0,
            .ps = 0x563ca42a2020,
            .bs = {
                .m = 0,
            },
        },
        // other 9 elements are omit
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> and when I do so, the process must not get disturbed - so attaching gdb to the process (which would stop it) is not an option.

I have modified gdb to avoid attaching.

With [this modified gdb](https://github.com/oufm/gdb), you can run `gdb -m <PID>` to explore the memory without stopping the process.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel Pin tool might be helpful, the `Pin_SafeCopy()` function can read memory at certain address. Descriptions can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/98612/Pin/doc/html/group__PIN__CONTROL.html#ga1225706d213f4bd1d81ed1fb32e792d7)

Answer (score -4):

i achieved this by issuing the below command

[root@stage1 ~]# echo "Memory usage for PID [MySql]:"; for mem in {Private,Rss,Shared,Swap,Pss};do grep $mem /proc/`ps aux |grep mysql |awk '{print $2}'|head -n 1`/smaps | awk -v mem_type="$mem" '{i=i+$2} END {print mem_type,"memory usage:"i}' ;done

**Result Output**

Memory usage for PID [MySql]:

Private memory usage:204

Rss memory usage:1264

Shared memory usage:1060

Swap memory usage:0

Pss memory usage:423

Comment: The question is not about memory usage