# How to a get a new virtual memory address to an already allocated page?

Tags: c, linux, memory

Can I receive a new virtual address for a page that is already allocated?

If so what are the system calls? (Preferably on linux)

Comment: That seems like such a dangerous thing to do. The kernel probably takes care of everything, but still. I wonder if you have a particular use-case in mind ?

Comment: The main reason is to remove use after free vul's. So that the original virtual addresses will still exist, and function, but will no longer point to what ever they referenced before (as it will be re-written).

Comment: Oh I misunderstood, I though you wanted two different virtual addresses pointing to the same physical page at the same time! Sorry. You'll probably want to look at mremap : http://linux.die.net/man/2/mremap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are asking here but:

- A little research (first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977179/reading-living-process-memory-without-interrupting-it-proc-kcore-is-an-option)) suggests you can do this in the general case by `mmap`'ing `/proc/PID/mem`. Not tried that, but assuming it works it will let you access the memory of the calling process or (subject to security) other processes.
- There are (to my knowledge) no direct system calls which allow you to create a new virtual address in a process's address space in respect of a page already allocated to a *different* process.
- There are (to my knowledge) no direct system calls which allow you to create a new virtual address in a process's address space in respect of a page already allocated to *the same* process, other than as a result of `mmap`.
- In respect of pages allocated with `mmap` to the same process, you might want to look at `mremap` and `remap_file_pages`.

Comment: Is there general documentation on linux's memory management system calls and interfaces? I tried searching but largely failed.