# Missing symbols when compiling a kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

When compiling a simple kernel module that uses the header `<asm/mmu_context.h>`, the compiler yells that there are missing symbols:

```
WARNING: "__tracepoint_tlb_flush"  undefined!
WARNING: "rdpmc_always_available" undefined!
```

Adding this simple statement:

```
 struct static_key rdpmc_always_available = STATIC_KEY_INIT_FALSE;
```

Solves the `rpdmpc_always_availble` missing symbol problem. I'm pretty sure adding this line isn't a good idea, because the kernel needs to have it already.

I can't find a solution for the other symbol.

Code is quite simple:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <asm/mmu_context.h>

int __init init_m(void)
{
    switch_mm(NULL, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I know it won't work, i'm just trying to figure out how to fix the symbols warnings.
\

Comment: Running `grep -sIrHn tlb_flush * | grep TRACE` command in kernel sources directory shows where `__tracepoint_tlb_flush` is declared and how it's being used. It's in [include/trace/events/tlb.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/trace/events/tlb.h#L37) file, declared at `TRACE_EVENT_CONDITION(tlb_flush,` line.

Comment: Btw, I'm not sure it's good idea to declare your own `rdpmc_always_available`, you can break module's logic. Look [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/mmu_context.h#L22).

Comment: Also, if you want any further assistance, please provide us with your module code.

Comment: @SamProtsenko, seems someone should learn `git grep` command and forget about sources from tarballs (besides useless use of double grep).

Comment: @AndyShevchenko It's true :) Old habits die hard. But I don't use tarballs and I'm using Git extensively. Using `git grep` the command from above turns into this one: `git grep -e tlb_flush --and \( -e TRACE \) -- '*.[ch]'`

Comment: @SamProtsenko I think mmu_context.h already includes tlb.h. the problem is there is no implementation for that function declaration

Comment: Calling `switch_mm` from the module seems to me a bad idea: only kernel core may call such low-level functions. And absent symbols just confirm that.

Comment: @RedWhistle What are you trying to achieve, in general? Perhaps we can help you to come up with right choice of API or propose you some different approach if you share your task with us.

Comment: @SamProtsenko  I'm trying to choose a random process and read its memory. i can't do that without using 'switch_mm()'.

Comment: @RedWhistle Why do you want to do that in kernel module? Wouldn't it be easy to do that in user-space, using `/proc/$pid/mem` file, for example? See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977179/reading-living-process-memory-without-interrupting-it-proc-kcore-is-an-option) and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux).

Comment: @SamProtsenko I already know about the '/proc/$pid/mem' trick. I'm just trying to exercise, studying the linux kernel. :)

Comment: @RedWhistle I really doubt that you are gonna encounter such a task in real world of kernel development. Basically because it should be done in user-space. If you are interested in that layer of kernel memory management API, I suggest you to develop your code right inside of kernel directory, as part of that memory management layer code, and not as a kernel module. That would eliminate your issues with missing symbols and make your coding much more fair (meaning that that API **should** be used only in that layer and not in upper layers, like kernel modules).

Comment: @SamProtsenko Well compiling the kernel is one solution, but i'm trying to do it via a kernel module. also, i know this kind of a task won't be common in the real world of kernel development, i'm just trying to fool around to understand memory management. If you have any other tasks for beginners, i'll be happy if you share them with me. (Already read 'Linux Kernel Develeopment 3rd edition'.)

Comment: @RedWhistle Depends on what you want to achieve. Kernel is a big place, so there is a **lot** of API there, and noone has overall knowledge on it. If you are looking forward to work in this area and are particularly interested in memory management, it may be helpful to know how to detect and fix memory leaks (see kmemleak), how to find and fix stack corruptions, how to find and fix memory fragmentation problem (those problems appeared in my practice, at least). You can look into [eudyptula challenge](http://eudyptula-challenge.org/) as well for further tasks.