# View variable's value of a running python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, variables, memory-management

I have a python script on Heroku and I have some data stored in a variable that should not be lost. So I can't kill the running python script and my "dumb" question is: is it possible to retrieve a variable value of a python script running on an os?
I am almost sure that it isn't somethingpossible, but it's just pure curiosity and if so, I'd like to know how. I have some knowledge over OS due to a university course and I know how pagination and segmentation work and how memory area are attached to processes, but maybe on linux, for example, giving to a bash script the root privileges it can discovery and read the memory that the process is referring to

Comment: why don't you just put in some code to write the value of the python variable to a file on the OS file system?

Comment: @JacobIRR I can't stop the script or I'll lose the variable's value of course... so where should I put this code?

PS. I have this problem because the script had to save this variable's value on a json, but heroku doesn't allow to write on the filesystem for various reasons. Now I need that value :)

Comment: oh, the script is already running at this very moment and you can't stop it? Or were you assuming you had to stop it in order to write to a file?

Comment: There are ways of doing this if the script was running on your own machine, eg by attaching a debugger like GDB. However, I very much doubt you'll be able to do that on Heroku.

Comment: @GiacomoCerquone if you have enough permissions, you could try remount file system in RW mode to allow it save on a JSON. Another way is to exploit the running python script (especially if you have sources!) and make it give up the precious data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977179/reading-living-process-memory-without-interrupting-it-proc-kcore-is-an-option