# What to do with a process dump?

Tags: linux, debugging, dump

I am trying to learn on a more deeper level how programs work. I came across someone writing about "process dumping" and that that person said process dumping might be a way to get information from a program. I have tried this [process dumping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977179/reading-living-process-memory-without-interrupting-it) (dr jimbob's answer) method on my Linux machine and got a huge file from the program I used the script on. It mostly contains stuff such as `^@^@^@��^Q^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@�^O^@^@���^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@` but there were some strings and lots of random information (e.g. libraries) in the file. I am guessing the @ signs and other random combinations of symbols are just stuff in the program that is not formated in UTF-8/letter format. I also tried [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux/6302#6302) and got lots of .dump files.

My question boils down to: How do I actually read the dump file and get relevant information? Is it not more efficient to do something like `strings file.dump` since what I am looking for is readable information, not @ signs?

Answer (score 0):

`strings file.dump` is perfectly fine, if you just want to examine some strings.

Usually, you want to examine function stack and values of specific variables (which are usually binary - so `strings` won't work). To do that you can load core dump into debugger, for example:

dump process 9319 (bash):

```
gcore 9319
```

load into gdb:

```
gdb bash core.9319
```

then proceed as if it were a live process. For example, dump stack trace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f5ef50318a7 in __GI___waitpid (pid=-1, stat_loc=0x7ffd567683d0, 
    options=10) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c:30
#1  0x000055ef3ea89869 in ?? ()
#2  0x000055ef3ea8acc3 in wait_for ()
#3  0x000055ef3ea78b85 in execute_command_internal ()
#4  0x000055ef3ea78df2 in execute_command ()
#5  0x000055ef3ea60833 in reader_loop ()
#6  0x000055ef3ea5f104 in main ()
```

or examine some global variables:

```
(gdb) print (int)history_length 
$1 = 81
```

it helps if your program has debug symbols (compiled with -g) - you will see a lot  more information

Comment: Doing your process results in the following errors inside gdb: `warning: core file may not match specified executable file.` and `warning: Section .reg/55397' in core file too small.`, and some other errors. Is there a difference in your method vs. the two methods I use? Do they produce the same data?

Comment: You need gdb compatible core dump for this to work. Looks like your two methods merge all memory regions together - gdb won't work for them.

Comment: just to clarify: I ran gdb exactly as you did on a dump of a process using gcore.

Comment: It should work then. Make sure you are passing the right binary to gdb (core has to match executable): `gdb [some_program] [core_dump_from_that_program]`

Comment: I am 100% sure it is the same binary. It has no global variables, nothing from `print`, nothing from `bt`. It is a program I have been working on for a couple of months and it has lots and lots of variables and other stuff. Weird.