# How can I access the RAM of a process that's no longer running?

Tags: memory, process, ram

I'm fairly new to all of this so bear with me. I want to find a way to access the RAM to see what's in there after my program finished. So let's say for example I wrote a C code that does malloc() for an array and puts stuff in there (e.g "ABCDEFG"), and I intentionally don't free it before the end of my code. I want to run my program and after it's finished, I want to take a look at my RAM to see if "ABCDEFG" is still there on the heap. I know that at the end of the program, the kernel takes back all the resources it has allocated but I don't think it empties the blocks, I think it just "free"s them from the process once it's done. But the data remains in the RAM and other programs later can overwrite it (please do correct me if any of my assumptions is wrong). I have tried :

- sudo cat /dev/mem => I didn't find the string there.
- The code given here : [Reading living process memory without interrupting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977179/reading-living-process-memory-without-interrupting-it) => the program requires the PID, which won't exist if my process isn't running.

Any insight/resource that could point me in the right direction would be appreciated !

**EDIT :** [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/621377/what-happens-to-my-data-in-ram-after-my-app-closes) seems to also share my opinion :

> When you allocate a certain amount of memory, it might have the data
> in it that was left there by a previous process (or another part of
> your application)

Comment: This is called memory scavenging. Google this out.

Comment: Sorry but could you elaborate a bit more? From what I read, I understood that the scavenging technique makes unused memory available to applications on other cluster nodes, which is applicable in the context of distributed systems. How does this relate to what I'm looking for ? Do you happen to have any links/resources I could use to dig more? Many thanks.

Comment: Well, not sure about distributed systems. However, assuming you ran a process that allocated memory and stored data in that memory then exited, the OS can then allocated this memory to other processes. Accordingly, if you launch a new process that allocates memory, it could in principle be allocated memory that was freed by the previous process. However, you have no guarantee as the OS could use that memory to read in the executable. So maybe it would be best to launch your scavenging executable prior to the existing of the target process. Still no guarantee it will work.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/110477/reading-physical-memory-frame-previously-owned-by-another-process-to-read-conten The kernel zeroes out memory before handing it over to new processes.